Синий экран при запуске виртуального девайса android studio
Скачал и установил андройд студио, создал виртуальное устройство и скачал андройд, при попытке запустить виртуалку вылетает синий экран:

CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT

Как говорят тут, мне нужно либо заменить "бракованный процессор", либо переустановить виндовс. Есть ли способ это исправить более простым путем? У меня Windows 10, проц - amd.

Еще можно блок питания заменить :) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/solved-event-id-1001-clockwatchdogtimeout-bsod-and/d4580535-90f3-4080-a8a2-b127dfb1fb5a

По моему опыту синий экран - это HDD когда начинает приезжать, но уже многие сидят на SSD.

Спасибо конечно за помощь, но мне кажется, что блок питания заменить будтет ни чуть не легче  . Я уже нашел решение (Просто использую физическое устройство)
